# is there a way to avoid eval() to accomplish dynamic dispatch of a function specified in a list in python

Tags: python, eval

I have a list as defined here:

```
header_fields = [
['delim',0,4,'strip()'],
['qual',4,5,None],
['NLS_CODE',6,25,'strip()'],
['source_system_id',26,45,'strip()'],
['extract_name',46,65,'strip()'],
['extract_serial_number',66,85,'strip()'],
['file_counter',86,88,"lstrip('0')"],
['total_file_count',89,91,'strip()'],
['extract_run_date_time',92,126,'strip()'],
['from_date',127,161,'strip()'],
['thru_date',162,196,'strip()'],
['number_of_rows',197,216,'strip()'],
['data_recons1',217,246,'strip()'],
['data_recons2',247,276,'strip()'],
['data_recons3',277,306,'strip()']
]
```

element[1] and element[2] are used to parse a line called `header`
I want to call element[3] for each element in `header_fields` like so:

```
for element in header_fields:
    a = header[element[1]:element[2]]
    if element[3] None:
        b = a
    else:
        b = eval('a.'+element[3])
```

Is there a way to restructure all of this to avoid eval? `ast.literal_eval('a.'+element[3])` throws 'malformed string'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the functions (with `functools.partial` or `lambda` when you need to pre-bind arguments) rather than their names.  E.g:

```
['delim',0,4,str.strip],
['qual',4,5,None],
['NLS_CODE',6,25,str.strip],
['source_system_id',26,45,str.strip],
['extract_name',46,65,str.strip],
['extract_serial_number',66,85,str.strip],
['file_counter',86,88, lambda s: s.lstrip('0')],
... etc ...
```

Then, where you're currently trying

```
b = eval('a.'+element[3])
```

use, instead

```
b = element[3](a)
```

If you know for sure you'll always want to call a **method** on `a` (possibly with arguments) you could use other approaches based on `getattr` (with the method name as a string), for example; but this approach is more general.

Answer (score 4):

There are a bunch of ways.  The most straightforward, given what you have at the moment, is probably to use `getattr`:

```
header_fields = [
['delim',0,4,'strip'],
['qual',4,5,None],
['NLS_CODE',6,25,'strip'],
['source_system_id',26,45,'strip'],
['extract_name',46,65,'strip'],
['extract_serial_number',66,85,'strip'],
['file_counter',86,88,'lstrip', ('0',)],
['total_file_count',89,91,'strip'],
['extract_run_date_time',92,126,'strip'],
['from_date',127,161,'strip'],
['thru_date',162,196,'strip'],
['number_of_rows',197,216,'strip'],
['data_recons1',217,246,'strip'],
['data_recons2',247,276,'strip'],
['data_recons3',277,306,'strip']
]
```

and then:

```
for element in header_fields:
    a = header[element[1]:element[2]]
    if element[3] is None:
        b = a
    else:
        args = element[4] if len(element) > 3 else ()
        b = getattr(a, element[3])(args)
```

Here, I've stashed arguments if any in `element[4]`, to provide the `'0'` to `lstrip`.

Personally I'd probably lean towards restructuring this some and maybe also using `functools.partial` as suggested in [Alex Martelli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28163192/1256452).